# Why doesn't flow debug info show in my debug log?

Tags: visual-workflow, debug-logs

- I'm logged into Salesforce Lightning, Health Cloud Admin
- I open the Developer Console and set the flow debug levels to finer
  [image]
- I go to an Account record and click Schedule Appointment
  [image]
- I complete the flow to schedule an appointment
- None of the flow info shows in the developer console... why?

[image]